# What is the name of the sea in this image?

Tags: geography

I was reading in Wikipedia about the [Indian Ocean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Ocean) and I saw there an image of the part of the globe with a "closed sea" (it's marked by a red arrow in the attached picture). What is the name of this sea?

[image]

Comment: Camilo Rada's already given you the right answer for this particular case, but in general there's an easy way to find out for yourself the name of any geographic feature if you know its location: you can go to https://www.google.com/maps/ (or whichever online mapping service you prefer), find the feature you're interested in, and zoom in on it. The feature will be labelled with its name on the map.

Comment: -1 I have no Idea why you couldn't just copy-paste the image into google images and found the answer there.

Comment: @Eevee, the only thing Google Images return is Indian Ocean (since that's what the graphic is actually about).  I'm guessing the orange arrow was added by the user.  So that method of search unfortunately won't work.  But Google Maps surely will help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's the [Caspian sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Sea), considered the largest enclosed inland body of water on Earth by area. It is bounded by Kazakhstan to the northeast, Russia to the northwest, Azerbaijan to the west, Iran to the south, and Turkmenistan to the southeast.